# How can I start an executable jar file from a desktop file in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, java

I have an executable jar file which I'd like to be able to start from a shortcut on either the desktop or the start menu.  I wrote a desktop file but I cannot get it to work no matter how I specify the Exec line.  The file currently reads as

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Party Planner
Exec=java -jar ~/Downloads/PartyPlanner.jar
```

When I click on the file on the desktop, absolutely nothing happens.  The command in the Exec line works perfectly well when I enter it in the terminal.  In fact, it works no matter what directory I'm in when I type it.  I've tried replacing "java" and "~/Downloads/PartyPlanner.jar" in the desktop file with their respective absolute paths, but that doesn't help.  I can't get this thing to work on either of my Lubuntu machines (one running 14.04 and the other 15.04).

What am I doing wrong?  Is there some log file somewhere I should be looking at for error messages?

Comment: Try it again with the absolute path of `~/Downloads/PartyPlanner.jar` and add exactly this desktop file into your question. `~` can't work.

Comment: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html

Comment: . . . it's working now.  Thank you.  For the record, I tried doing the absolute path before posting the question.  I see now that I had a typo then--I capitalized my user name rather than going with all lower case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use the `~` in your desktop file. Replace `~` with the output of

   ```
   echo /home/$USER
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   Exec=java -jar /home/john/Downloads/PartyPlanner.jar
   ```
2. Use

   ```
   Path=/home/john/Downloads/
   Type=Application
   ```