# How to configure .desktop file to run .jar file exactly as if run from terminal

Tags: .desktop, execute-command, jar

I have a java program that works correctly when I run `java -jar "lizzie.jar"` from the terminal, but when I double click it in Nautilus it runs (i.e. UI shows) but returns the error "No such file or directory" for one of the files (./leelaz) it depends on to work properly.

I have created a .desktop file in `/home/username/.local/share/applications` with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Lizzie
Type=Application
Exec=java -jar "/home/username/opt/Lizzie/lizzie.jar"
Icon=/home/username/opt/Lizzie/lizzie_custom_logo.png
Comment=Lizzie
Terminal=false
```

Running this yields the same error as double-clicking.

I found and read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756976/unable-to-run-jar-file-using-desktop-file-even-though-it-runs-from-terminal) post, and I've tried using both `Terminal=true` and `Terminal=false`. The file lizzie.jar is set to allow executing as program and both when running from Nautilus and terminal I am not root. This might of course be an issue for Lizzie and not Ubuntu, but I think I should be able to generate the same behavior as if run from terminal.

**Dist:** Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS;
**Kernel:** 5.4.0-99-generic

`java -version` returns:

```
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Question:** What is the likely reason the behavior from double-clicking and running the .desktop is different from terminal, and how may I configure a .desktop file that gives exactly the same behavior as if I ran `java -jar lizzie.jar` from the terminal?

*N.B. The program runs in both cases, but it can't access the dependency `./leelaz` in the case of double-clicking or using .desktop. Lizzie then reports: `Cannot run program "./leelaz": error=2, No such file or directory.` But, the file `./leelaz` is there, and again, everything works when run from terminal.*

*(In case of interest, the application is [Lizzie](https://github.com/featurecat/lizzie), an interface for the Go AI Leela Zero.)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I start an executable jar file from a desktop file in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684581/how-can-i-start-an-executable-jar-file-from-a-desktop-file-in-lubuntu)

Comment: Possibly related: [Why isn't tilde recognised as home folder in this case?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192981/why-isnt-tilde-recognised-as-home-folder-in-this-case)

Comment: @MartinThornton I'm afraid it doesn't, and I have edited the question; I only wrote '~' in the path to avoid writing my username, but ofcourse I can just write anything, I just thought they were equivalent. The actual path is complete in the .desktop file.

Comment: Also, as pointed out, the app does start, i.e. the gui of the application shows, but I get an error. This is why I wrote that it might be a question for the Lizzie-devs, but I think it is strange that it does work from the terminal, so that I feel I should be able to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the likely reason the behavior from double-clicking and
> running the .desktop is different from terminal

When successfully running `java -jar "lizzie.jar"`, your current working directory is the same as the directory where the file `lizzie.jar` resides. Otherwise, `lizzie.jar` would not be found.

`lizzie.jar` apparently expects to find files it needs in its own directory. You therefore need to make sure to set the current directory to that where "lizzie.jar" resides.

> how may I configure a .desktop file that gives exactly the same
> behavior as if I ran java -jar lizzie.jar from the terminal?

Add the following desktop entry to the `.desktop` launcher:

```
Path=/home/username/opt/Lizzie/
```

Comment: This solved my problem! I am a bit curious as to why double-clicking the .jar file gave the same behavior though; wouldn't the working directory just be set to the directory of the file I am double clicking?

Comment: Launching a file by double clicking launches it in the directory where it resides.

Comment: Exactly, and this is `/home/username/opt/Lizzie/` , i.e. the same as the path I set in .desktop which made the desktop-launcher work.